Who is "A person" in, "A person cannot receive even one thing....". John 3:27?
John 3:27 ESV

"John answered, "A person cannot receive even  one thing unless it is given him from heaven." My emphasis. [anthropos/a person]

From John 3:26

"He is baptizing and all are going to him".

Jesus is in the immediate context of v27.
From John 3:28

"I am not the Christ."

Here another person, John, is in the immediate context.
From Job 1:12

"do not lay a hand on his person."

The Lord said this to Satan. It shows that what happened to Job, Job received under the Lord, or heaven's, control.
From Acts 12:23

"Immediately an angel of the Lord struck him down,".

Here a person, Herod, received something from heaven.
In John 3:27 could "anthropos" be either "a person", or "man" or even "mankind"  i.e., "mankind" not just anyone, but everyone? Does "a person" mean everyone?

As Thayer notes, ἄνθρωπος without the article (i.e., indefinite) can be used in the sense of “someone...when who he is either is not known or is not important” and thus “equivalent to τὶς [anyone; someone]”. Also, he notes, “where what is said holds of every man, so that ἄνθρ[ωπος] is equiv[alent] to the Germ[an] indef[inite] man, one”.





Footnotes




1 Thayer, p. 46, ἄνθρωπος, 2., a. and b.






References




Wilke, Christian Gottlob. A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament: Being Grimm Wilke’s Clavis Novi Testamenti. Trans. Thayer, Joseph Henry. Ed. Grimm, Carl Ludwig Wilibald. Rev. ed. New York: American Book, 1889.




@ Der Ubermensch Sorry I'm struggling with your answer. You quote Thayer  saying "when he is not known or is not important". Jesus and John the B. were both known and important so does that limit this "anthropos" to just them?

@C.Stroud—Yes, they are both known, but they are not important insofar as the maxim [stated in John 3:27]  applies to everyone.
